# Is php able to echo plain text which serves html/css div elements as a class tag?

Tags: php

```
<div id="myProfile" <?php if($_GET['page'] == 'myProfile'){echo 'class="show"';}else{echo 'class="hide"';} ?>>
    div content which should be shown/hidden...
</div>
```

My div doesn't hide when I click a link which adds 'page=myProfile' to the URL.
This `if()` php statement is supposed to echo my css class 'show' and 'hide' when the site is & is not 'myProfile'. Does anyone see an error? I'm giving up now for real…

Comment: For handling event such as click, you should use javascript instead

Comment: i did but for example oncklick() doesnt work on old android webbrowsers or ios :/ @VincentG